# Facebook app not asking permission for manage_pages, but I have this permission

Tags: php, facebook

I have approved manage_page permissions, but when the user do login, Facebook ask only on the: email, public_profile and user_friends.

My code in php to take de pages and link from the user is:

```
$request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me/accounts/user?fields=name,id,fan_count');
        $response = $request->execute();
        $accounts = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();
```

The screenshot of the permission of my app is:
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByQWh.gif)

Comment: the most interesting question is: how did you even get it approved by facebook, if you don´t even use it?

Comment: My php code should return the pages and likes.
I use test users and working properly

Answer (score 0):

What the screenshot shows are the permissions that are approved for your app by Facebook, meaning those are the permissions you *can* ask normal users for.

That does of course not mean that individual users have automatically *granted* that permission to your app – you still *have to ask them* for it.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/requesting-and-revoking

Comment: My php code should return the pages and likes.
I use test users and working properly

Comment: Show the part where you are asking the user for those permissions. (Edit your question please.)

Comment: I don't ask to those permissions, simply I do request to /me/accounts/user. How I need to do in PHP ?

Comment: Of course you need to ask users for permissions first. How to do that, is described in the documentation section I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all, my problem was that a don't have defined the $scope=array('email','public_profile','user_friends');

Now my scope is: $scope=array('email','public_profile','user_friends','manage_pages');

and function ok !